# How much to "automatically" do?

Tags: programming-practices

I'm reading Code Complete 2, and I'm at the chapter where it says to (paraphrasing) "avoid programming through the interface."  Why is it bad to program "through" the interface?

A more concrete example: if I have a method of a class that submits a funny picture, what's wrong with it logging me in also?  Should I simply provide more "helper" methods that do it automatically?

Would it be preferred to break it up into:

- set_login(username, password)
- login()
- submit_picture(funny_picture)
- easy_submit(funny_picture) # where it will log in (if not already) and submit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, shorter methods are more readable and easier to test with unit tests. Even if you do not plan to reuse the login and/or submit method, breaking it down makes testing and maintenance easier.

Answer (score 4):

It's elementary, my dear Watson! Code Reuse. When you separate the task of login and sending picture, some one else can also use your login, and someone else can also use your send_picture. Moreover if you have login and send_picture separate, how difficult is it to create easy_submit?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong or correct it depends on the level which that code is going to be used of. What will happen, if you want to submit more than one picture? On this example, I would divide it into two levels, say, `core` and `application`. The core level provides basic facilities (`login(u, p)` and `submit_data(data, type)`), and the application layer provides helper methods. And would use them appropriately depending on the context.